# MySql server 5.0.96 hangs on sometimes

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a problem with my MySQL server, version 5.0.96. Database with all InnoDB tables is running on server.
Sometimes during heavy workloads, all clients at same time experience unresponsive MySQL server. Sometimes after couple of minutes server recovers, but sometimes only restarting MySQL service helps.
When there is no many clients connected server works perfectly. Number of connections also is not a problem, i checked and number is 300-400 connections during heavy workload and we set maximum number of connections to 5000.
There is 32GB RAM memory on machine and quad core processor, so this should be enough.
InnoDB parameters from server are

```
innodb_thread_concurrence = 200
innodb_open_files = 2048
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120
innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8192M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 8M
innodb_concurrency_tickets = 500
innodb_commit_concurrency = 16
innodb_autoextend_increment = 8
innodb_adaptive_hash_index enabled
```

Somewhere i read that innodb_thread_concurrence should not be larger than 16. Is it maybe large value of this parameter cause that server hangs on?

Answer (score 0):

**5.0** InnoDB bogs down after about 4-8 *active* users.  5000 *idle* users is no problem.

When you have more than, say, 8 users, they are stumbling over each other, and each one takes longer and longer to finish.  Meanwhile more users are trying to get in; this only aggravates the situation.  This is probably when you decide to reboot.  Another solution would be to stop the clients from starting any more connections.

What are your **clients**?  If they are running in Apache, keep MaxClients rather low, say, 10.  This keeps from overloading MySQL, and makes it easier for your code to give users something more graceful than a crash.

**5.6** has a lot of fixes in this area.  I recommend you upgrade.  (You are 3 major steps behind, so the upgrade will be painful.)

I have, so far, ignored your settings, since you "cannot tune your way out of a performance problem" (usually).  Now I will look.

Do you know if you are I/O bound when the problem occurs?  If so, consider changing

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit from 1 to 2
```

This would be less safe, but it would cut down significantly on I/O.

Can you batch statements into `BEGIN...COMMIT` blocks?  That leads to less I/O.

Do you have spare RAM?  Do you have more than 8GB of data and indexes?  (Apparently you have 7.43GB.)  If so, increase

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size from 8192M to 70% of _available_ RAM
```

Increase it to 9G anyway.

Oh, bad:

```
query_cache_size = 512M
```

When *any* write occurs to a table, *all* mentions of that table need to be purged from the **Query Cache**.  This *may* be costly.  I recommend no more than 50M for that setting.  In write-busy systems I recommend turning OFF the QC.

You say "all InnoDB", yet you are wasting 2GB for MyISAM:  `key_buffer_size = 2048M`.  Change that to 20M.

You have the **slowlog** turned on, but probably at the default threshold of 10 seconds.  Decrease it to 2 sec.  But perhaps even at 10, you have already caught some of the queries that led to crashing.  Look in the slowlog (better yet, use pt-query-digest to summarize it).  Let's discuss the worst couple of queries.  Cleaning up one of them *might* be the total solution.

Comment: I changed server parameters as you suggested, situation on heavy load is better, but still, users experience server inactivity sometimes. It is better now, because server is inactive for short time. I can see from CPU monitor that processor is almost at 100% in this situation, but one of the cores, other three are on 20%. It is quad core processor on machine where server is deployed. Is it possible that MySQL 5.0.96 cannot use all CPU cores? Regarding: innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit from 1 to 2 what you mean by "This would be less safe"? Is there any possibility to data loss or something?

Comment: One connection uses at most one CPU.  So, it sounds like you have a slow query that is hanging onto a CPU.  Let's see it and see if something can be done to speed it up.

Comment: `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2` flushes the transaction log once a second.  If the system crashed during the second, then some transactions _may_ be lost.

Comment: I just reproduced server hanging out. From what i saw, RAM was OK, CPU also, but disk activity was huge and now i think maybe that is limitation factor. What is suggested to prevent disk activity which cause server inactive?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your version is old enough to have the nasty problem that Percona was first to fix.  Every few minutes, virtually all connections stopped getting anything done -- pending writes from the buffer_pool were being flushed too aggressively.  Upgrade to 5.5 at least.